# scrolling div not scrolling on page load

Tags: html, safari, scroll, mousewheel

I've seen a similar question but it's quite different.

I have a div that i want scrollable. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't work in Safari. At least it doesn't work when i load the page. I have to resize the window or zoom in/out the page for the scroll to "unlock". This only affects mouse wheel scrolling. The traditional drag scrolling works well.

The test site is here: http://dmd.esad.pt/e512/final/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with $(window).load function and with help of [malihu's jquery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) but i believe i could just use a simple .load